# Difference between this.openOrCreateDatabase() and SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I was trying to create a sqlite database using android when I came across this.

There are 2 methods `this.openOrCreateDatabase()` and `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()`

What is the difference between these two and which one should be used

Answer (score 0):

`this` will call the method on your instantiated object for the class you are currently defining.

`SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()` will call the static method defined in the `SQLiteDatabase`  class.

```
public class YourObject {
   //constructor

   public void openOrCreateDatabase() {
       //do something special
   }

   public void methodYouAreWriting() {
       this.openOrCreateDatabase() //do something special - interacts with YourObject::openOrCreateDatabase
   }

   public void methodYouAreWritingToOpenSQLiteDatabase() {
       SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase() // Interacts with SQLiteDatabase class.
   }
```

Comment: How will we know that we have to create an object like that? For some classes we use `new` keyword, some we use `Classname.methodWhichReturnsObject` or some like this. How can we determine how object can be created for a particular class?